# The socle of cokernel of irreducible monomorphisms in the AR quiver of type An/I is simple

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

The socle of cokernel of irreducible monomorphisms in the AR quiver of type An/I is simple.

I believe that this result is hidden in a more general result in some 
articles, I tried to find a lot but failed.

The following lemma maybe useful:

M be a module of length n. TFAE:

1 SocM is simple

2 Any non-zero submodule of M is indecomposable

3 There exists a composition series of M with all terms indecomposable

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Do you assume your $A_n$-quiver to be linearly oriented?

Comment: In fact here the orientation and admissable ideal I are all arbitrary. @Julian Kuelshammer

Comment: Every non-projective indecomposable module is the cokernel of an irreducible monomorphism, namely the left almost split morphism in the AR-sequence. I think you mean *irreducible monomorphisms between indecomposable modules*.

Answer (score 3):

This is more generally true for any representation-finite string algebra (provided as Dag Madsen pointed out you are talking about irreducible maps between indecomposable modules, otherwise every non-projective module is a cokernel of an irreducible monomorphism). String algebras are a subclass of the class of special biserial algebras, where the admissible ideal of the quiver is spanned by zero relations.

For this class of algebras, all indecomposable modules are given by strings (i.e. words in the arrows of the quiver and their inverses such that there is no cancellation). This is essentially due to Gelfand and Ponomarev, see 
*I. M. Gel'fand and V. A. Ponomarev*, MR0229751 [**Indecomposable representations of the Lorentz group.**](http://www.iop.org/EJ/abstract/0036-0279/23/2/R01), *Russian Mathematical Surveys* **23** (1968), no. 2, 3--60. The general case is is stated e.g. in *Burkhard Wald and Josef Waschbüsch*, MR 801283 [**Tame biserial algebras**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(85)90119-X), *J. Algebra* **95** (1985), no. 2, 480--500.

In this case the irreducible monomorphisms are given by appending hooks to a given string. This is proven in *M. C. R. Butler and Claus Michael Ringel*, MR 876976 [**Auslander-Reiten sequences with few middle terms and applications to string algebras**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/00927878708823416), *Comm. Algebra* **15** (1987), no. 1-2, 145--179. Thus, the cokernel of an irreducible monomorphism is just the end of a hook, hence has simple socle.

Comment: You can sometimes append hooks to both ends of the string, can't you? Are you (and the OP) assuming that the target of the irreducible monomorphism is an indecomposable module?

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen Thanks, I was implicitly assuming the OP meant this.

Comment: Perhaps when he writes "irreducible monomorphisms in the AR quiver" he is referring to (a subset of) the arrows in the AR quiver.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments! What I mean precisely is all the irreducible morphisms between indecomposable modules in the AR quiver, i.e, all the arrows in the quiver. @Dag Oskar Madsen

Comment: For the last sentence, why the end of a hook has a simple socle, or equivalently has a unique simple submodule? Thanks a lot for explanation!

Comment: In my language,  here the arrows between the non-zero vertices of the representation of a cokernel is always linear, therefore it has a unique submodule S(i) with i the target of the representation.  Can I understand it in this way for the case An/I ?

Comment: @milanelo The cokernel of an irreducible monomorphism will always be a uniserial module, in particular will have simple socle.

Comment: Thanks for all the explanations again! I will read the related articles to understand this problem.